# A stacked bar graph in android in simplest way in android

Tags: android, graph, stacked-area-chart, android-graphview

i want to make a stacked graph as shown below image in android without using [AchartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: how unfair some people are when they dont know the answres and give -ve to others question...bulshit..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uncomfotable with AchartEngine then, you can use Use [charts4j](https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/BarChartExample.java#51)

> charts4j is a chart API for Java that developers can use in their Java
>   code to programmatically generate nearly all the charts available in
>   Google Chart Tools.

You can also [check here](https://github.com/julienchastang/charts4j).

Hope this helps..